# CoreGraphics framework does not compile in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently tried upgrading an Xcode project from Xcode 7 to the Xcode 8 GM seed. However the code would not compile due to the CoreGraphics framework, all of the header files reference 'CGRect', 'CGPoint', etc and those types give compile errors as 'Unknown type name'

I then just created a new project in Xcode 8, added the CoreGraphics framework and observed the same compile time errors.

Is this framework broken in Xcode 8 or is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to use `CGRectMake` by chance?

Comment: "added the CoreGraphics framework" There is nothing to add. Core Graphics is effectively part of UIKit. You're doing something simple and silly, but you are giving no clue as to what it is. If you really want help, _show_ what you're doing. Show your code, show the error messages.

Comment: I deleted the Xcode 8 GM application and reinstalled it and now the Coregraphics framework compiles. The actual framework didn't compile before in a completely empty Xcode project (without any of my own code) however it seems to compile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import below lines in your class,

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

  #include <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
```